# Kotlin + RX Observer sem Anonymous

Tags: java, android, expressões-lambda, kotlin, reactive-programming

Estou estudando Kotlin Android e RX e so vejo exemplos como :

```
val api = StarWarsService()
api.loadMovies()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        {
                            movie -> movies?.add("${movie.title} - ${movie.epsodeId}")
                        },{
                            e -> e.printStackTrace()
                        },{

                        })
```

Isso dentro do .subscribe é um Observer anonimo com lambda, é isso mesmo?

Tentei fazer algo como igual ja fiz no java em outros estudos:

```
Pessoa p = new Pessoa("João");

        Observable<Pessoa> observable = Observable.just(p);

        Observer<Pessoa> observer = new Observer<Pessoa>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                Log.i("app", "Completado");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.i("app", "Erro");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Pessoa pessoa) {
                Log.i("app", "onNext" + pessoa.getNome());
            }
        };

        observable.subscribe(observer);
```

O problema não é o lambda, queria criar um objeto Observer ou Subscribe e passar para .subscribe(observer) igual no exemplo acima do Java.

Tem como????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No primeiro exemplo que você mostrou, estão sendo passados três lambdas (e não um `Observer`).

Está sendo invocado o overload com a assinatura: `subscribe(Consumer<? super T> onNext, Consumer<? super Throwable> onError, Action onComplete)`.

Para fazer o que você quer no Kotlin basta criar uma *object expression*,  como [exemplificado na documentação da linguagem](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions):

```
val observable = Observable.just("Hello", "World")
val observer = object : Observer<String> {
  override fun onComplete() {

  }

  override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {

  }

  override fun onNext(t: String) {

  }

  override fun onError(e: Throwable) {

  }
}

observable.subscribe(observer)
```